# Vue JS - Add dynamic component based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue JS and I have below requirement

**Requirement :**

I have dropdown with below values

[image]

On selection of each value, I want to add dropdown component on page, which are already defined.
For example:

- On Selection of 'Closed', dropdown component (which is searchable dropdown)will be added
- On Selection of 'Reviewed', another dropdown component where user can select values from dropdown. (not searchable one). Likewise..

**What I have :**

- I already have all the different types of dropdowns as a component.

**What I tried :**

- I have loaded all the four types of dropdown on page load, and I am hiding and showing them based on dropdown value selection.
- Example: I am showing only searchable dropdown component when user select 'Closed' option and hiding other components. I am showing selectable dropdown component when user select 'Reviewed' option and hiding other components.

**Problem :**

- Now the requirement is, user can select any option N number of times and on each selection, respective dropdown component should get added.
- This screen also have edit functionality.

**Note :**

- Consider this as a filter functionality with below screen
  [image]

Any help / pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

First you should create Closed and Reviewed components

[image: enter image description]

Then, you should have a array of filters:

```
data() { return {
  filters: [],
} }
```

When Add filter is clicked you should push corresponding component to filters, something like:

```
methods: {
  addFilter() {
    const component = Created /* */;
    this.filters.push({
      value: null,
      component: component
    })
  }
}
```

And finally render them in template this way:

```
<div v-for="(filter, index) in filters" :key="index">
  <component :is="filter.component" />
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-filters-demo-nfx5r)

---

For `And/Or` dropdowns, you can use some hacks but I'm not sure how to implement them (you can check if index is zero to only display them *between* filters)